# Read data from txt file in dictionary format

Tags: python, dictionary, file-handling

how do I convert a data read from a txt file in dictionary format.

Lines from txt file:

```py
A1, 5, Apples
B1, 3, Oranges
```

Desired output:

```py
{'A1':[5.0,'Apples'], 'B1':[3.0,'Oranges']}
```

only managed to code these:

```py
fr = open('products.txt','r')
for line in fr.readlines():
    code, name, price = line.split(',')
    print(line)
    
    fr.close()
```

Comment: what is the logic for selecting dictionary keys and values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use comprehension:

```
result = {line.strip().split(',')[0]: [line.strip().split(',')[1], line.strip().split(',')[2]] for line in open('products.txt','r')}
```

Or without comprehension:

```
result = {}

with open('products.txt','r') as fr:
    for line in fr:
        parts = line.strip().split(',')
        result[parts[0]] = [parts[1], parts[2]]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict = {}
fr = open('products.txt','r')
    for line in fr.readlines():
        code, name, price = line.split(',')
        my_dict[code] = [name,price]
        print(line)
    
    fr.close()
```

Comment: While that may answer the question it would be good if you also add some explanation to your answer, for example how the code works etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `empty dictionary` and `update` the dictionary for each lines, also strip off the value for price to get rid of residue space after splitting on comma:

```py
data = {}

fr = open('products.txt','r')
for line in fr.readlines():
    code, price, name = line.split(',')   # price is the middle item, name is last
    print(line)
    data.update({code:[float(price.strip()), name.strip()]})
    
fr.close()   #Keep this outside the loop
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
{'A1': [5.0, 'Apples'], 'B1': [3.0, 'Oranges']}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing, I just copied the code from the question so

Comment: i got an error, ValueError: could not convert string to float

Comment: That is because you have `code, name, price = line.split(',')` change it to `code, price, name= line.split(',')`

Comment: I have added the output as well, check once @zeerock

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you've got a few errors and a few missing things...

```
out_d = {}  # init an empty dict
fr = open('products.txt','r')
for line in fr.readlines():
    code, price, name = line.split(', ') # not code, name, price
    print(line)
    out_d[code] = [float(price), name]  # adds a new dict entry
fr.close()  # gets dedented
print(out_d)
```

A few things...
(1) according to your input file, you want to split on `', '`, not just `','`
(2) it looks like the order of your input file is code/price/name not code/name/price
(3) you need to cast the price from string to float
(4) your `fr.close()` is indented too far. It needs to be dedented.

Also, it's fine to do an `open()` and `close()` when you're first starting out. But there is a better way to go, called a context manager, which will automatically do the `close()` for you. Basically, it would look like this:

```
out_d = {}  # init an empty dict
with open('products.txt','r') as fr:  # this creates a context
    for line in fr.readlines():
        code, price, name = line.split(', ') # not code, name, price
        print(line)
        out_d[code] = [float(price), name]
# fr.close() -- this line now goes away
print(out_d)
```

Above, the `fr.close()` line goes away, because the `with open` calls `close` when the `with` block finishes.